# What is the Cauchy's integral formula for this?

Tags: integration, solution-verification, cauchy-integral-formula

$$\oint_{c : |z -\pi i| = 1} \frac{e^{iz}}{z(z-\pi i)^2} dz $$

I tried to solve it and the answer is $-\frac{1}{\pi} + i$
How can I make sure that the answer is right ?

Comment: I added a picture but it didn't appear

Comment: Edited your question, can you please check if the edit is correct?

Comment: Yes it is Thanks 

Comment: The best way would be to post your work here, so that someone could check it. (It is not just the end result, it is the *work* that matters too.) I appreciate you may have trouble with typing your answer in MathJax (for that, see the guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference ). With that, you may want to add the `solution-verification` tag.

Comment: Thank you, this is my first post . I appreciate your help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

z = 0 is not inside the contour.  That leaves only one pole inside the contour at $z = \pi i$

Cauchy integral formula says that is $f$ is holomorphic, for every $a$ inside the contour,

$\oint \frac {f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}} \ dz = \frac {2\pi i}{n!} f^{(n)}(a)$

$\frac {d}{dz} \frac {e^{iz}}{z} = \frac {e^{iz}(iz - 1)}{z^2}$

Evaluated at $z = \pi i$

$\frac {2\pi i}{1!}\frac {e^{-\pi}(-\pi - 1)}{-\pi^2}\\
\frac {2ie^{-\pi}(\pi + 1)}{\pi}$

Comment: Yes it is $e^{iz}$ . Isn't it   $\oint \frac {f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}} \ dz = (2\pi i )/n! f^{(n)}(a) $ ??

Comment: Yes, you are correct about the statement of Cauchy's theorem, I will fix it.  Fortunately $n = 1$ in this case and 1! = 1.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's help a lot